# Sybase Run SQL Generated From Previous Query

Tags: sql, sybase

I am generating SQL commends using Sybase to insert some new rows into a table based on the previous contents (working with an old ORM) and was wondering if there is a way to execute generated SQL without copy and paste?

I'm using something like

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Mapper VALUES (''' + ClassName + ''', ''NewObject'', ''NewId'', '''+convert(varchar(10), max(Sequence)+1)+''')'
FROM Mapper WHERE ClassName IN ('James', 'Steve') GROUP BY ClassName
```

For a table like

```
ClassName | ObjectName | ID | Sequence
```

This outputs results like:

```
 INSERT INTO Mapper VALUES ('James', 'NewObject', 'NewId', '38')           
 INSERT INTO Mapper VALUES ('Steve', 'NewObject', 'NewId', '24')
```

Is it possible to now run this genereated SQL without having to copy and paste within Sybase with just SQL (using Aqua Data Studio)?

Currently I just copy and paste it back into the same window

Thanks,

--

Note if this makes any difference it'll be for 2000+ rows

P.s. I've just noticed I used the word like a lot, sorry ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `CURSOR` on your statement, and the `EXEC` command to execute the SQL generated in each row.

I'm assuming this is a one off task, rather than an ongoing process, and there's a reason why you don't use `INSERT table SELECT....`

Comment: Yeh, you're correct this is a one off bulk task, though I'd forgotten about INSERT SELECT, i'll try with CURSOR anyway as I've not used it before